# Webdriver Exception - Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on selenium for quite a while now, recently I encountered a problem.
When I run my automation it gets stuck and stops working on random parts of the code, and sends back webdriver exception.
Now I'm losing my mind because of it, I just can't understand why it happens it doesn't make any sense.
Just now I tried it twice and it stopped in two different locations.
If anyone could help me it would be great!

Comment: can't help too much without the error itself. what is it?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <......>...</i> is not clickable at point (1271, 428). Other element would receive the click: <......>...</div>                                            Thats what it sends back... There is no reason that it will suddenly will be unable to click it at this point

Comment: that says something is blocking the click. Does that second element overlap the first?

Comment: Please provide some code, what changed some new dependancy, what is exception and so on.

Comment: The element that was supposed to be clicked appears only after you move on the element, but i added timeouts so it won't be a problem.  It shouldn't have this problem suddenly out of nowhere... It worked perfectly two days ago, suddenly yesterday it started making problems

Comment: @Kovacic I sent the exception above... nothing have changed! thats what making me go nuts. its like one moment everything works perfectly and then it started having problem, just doesn't make sense

Comment: As I mentioned at first, the code worked perfectly. then one moment it started having webdriver exceptions in random places on code everytime stops in a different place.

Comment: No chance to find the cause without html source code and your code. First tip, add explicit wait before clicking an element:  WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
WebElement blahblah = wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(blahblah's locator)); blahblah.click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception for which line you are getting, it says ELement is not clickable

Replace click event with action class, which will solve this Exception

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement("Your Webelement").click().perform();
```

Comment: I don't think this will change anything.

Comment: @pburgr Answers are always based on Experience, How can u say without performing it.

Comment: my exp says if an element is not clickable, than is not clickable by both approaches element.click(); even Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Comment: @pburgr And you can check my experience in my accepted answers. 
It will only not work, if page is not loaded correctly.

Comment: we didn't see yakir's html even his attempt. no point to argou without seeing the code.

Comment: @pburgr In my experience sometimes element.click() doesn't always work.... thanks Shah I'll check it now

Comment: @yakirsaadia Please accept answer and upvote, If you think it has helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: @pburgr We don't always need HTML code, Based on Exception type we can trace and solve it.

Comment: @IshitaShah accepted and tried to upvote I think it did. you realy solved me a huge problem thanks!